# jquery script not executing in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, minimize

I'm using a script that minimizes my top menu when scrolling the page down. The script is working just fine in Chrome and Safari but in Firefox it won't minimize.

Here's the page: http://smedjan.macework.se/boende/

Here's my script:

```
$(function(){
        $('#menubar').data('size','big');
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var $nav = $('#menubar');
        if ($('body').scrollTop() > 10) {
            if ($nav.data('size') == 'big') {
                $nav.data('size','small').stop().animate({
                    height:'50px',
                    top:'0px'
                }, 600);
            }
        } else {
            if ($nav.data('size') == 'small') {
                $nav.data('size','big').stop().animate({
                    height:'150px',
                    top:'20px'
                }, 600);
            }  
        }
    });

    $(function(){
        $('.smedjanlogo').data('size','big');
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var $nav = $('.smedjanlogo');
        if ($('body').scrollTop() > 10) {
            if ($nav.data('size') == 'big') {
                $nav.data('size','small').stop().animate({
                    height:'50px'
                }, 600);
            }
        } else {
            if ($nav.data('size') == 'small') {
                $nav.data('size','big').stop().animate({
                    height:'auto'
                }, 600);
            }  
        }
    });
```

Comment: can u explain what part is not working ..

Comment: @TusharGupta I think the OP explained it pretty well: "...in Firefox it won't minimize."

Comment: Could you post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), rather than your website?

Comment: @webeno yeah on window scroll not minimizing .

Comment: This statement "if ($('body').scrollTop() > 10)"

Changes to "if ($(window).scrollTop()>10)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying to fix your problem I could not help myself notice few facts -

1. You are not initializing your codes inside `$(document).ready()`. you are using them outside, so there might be a possibility that sometimes, jQuery will not be loaded before you use it -
2. FireFox does not work scroll with `body` as @Tushar mentioned.
3. In firefox, while scrolling multiple events are fired, so there is no check that whether a scrolling animation is taking place.

So I have taken the liberty to optimize your code a little -

```
$(function(){
    var scrolling = false;
    $('#menubar').data('size','big');
    $('.smedjanlogo').data('size','big');
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if(!scrolling){
            scrolling = true;
            var $nav = $('#menubar');
            if ($(document).scrollTop() > 10) {
                if ($nav.data('size') == 'big') {
                    $nav.data('size','small').stop().animate({
                        height:'50px',
                        top:'0px'
                    }, 600);
                }
            } else {
                if ($nav.data('size') == 'small') {
                    $nav.data('size','big').stop().animate({
                        height:'150px',
                        top:'20px'
                    }, 600);
                }  
            }

            $nav = $('.smedjanlogo');
            if ($(document).scrollTop() > 10) {
                if ($nav.data('size') == 'big') {
                    $nav.data('size','small').stop().animate({
                        height:'50px'
                    }, 600, null);
                }
            } else {
                if ($nav.data('size') == 'small') {
                    $nav.data('size','big').stop().animate({
                       height:'auto'
                    }, 600, null);
                }  
            }

            setTimeout(function(){
                 scrolling = false;
                 $(window).scroll();            
            },600);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the version I used while testing in firefox javascript console. Hope this helps.

Comment: It works just fine with this optimization. I'm gonna stick with this one to be on the safe side. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try

Change

```
if ($('body').scrollTop() > 10) {
```

to

```
if ($('body, html').scrollTop() > 10) {
```

Or

```
if ($(document).scrollTop() > 10) {
```

---

Firefox places the `overflow` to html instead of `body` tag .

So use `$('body, html').scrollTop()` which will work on chrome,Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

This is Firefox problem. Don't use $('body').scrollTop() for getting scroll position.

Firefox has the overflow at html-level and not body-level as the webkit based browser.

you can use

```
$('body, html').scrollTop() > 10
```